# ¿Es un buen método para hacer una página con controlador?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

estoy haciendo un proyecto de fin de curso, donde todo el contenido (excepto login) que se muestra en la pantalla se carga sobre el index, la cosa es que estoy controlando las redirecciones de la siguiente forma:

**Index.php**(ejemplos)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <ETIQUETAS/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <?php include header; ?>
        </header>
        <cuerpo>
        </cuerpo>
        <footer>
            <?php include footer; ?>
        </footer>
        <script>
            //esto para cada botón del header 
            $(botones).click($("cuerpo").load(".Controller/PageController.php", {"metodo":"cargaX"}));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP** (PageController.php)

```
class PageController{
    public static function ejecuta($metodo){
        $self::metodo();
    }

    public function metodo1(){/*Carga un código html que carga en cuerpo a traves de una clase View*/}
    public function metodo2(){/*Carga un código html que carga en cuerpo a traves de una clase View*/}
    public function metodo3(){/*Carga un código html que carga en cuerpo a traves de una clase View*/}
    public function metodo4(){/*Carga un código html que carga en cuerpo a traves de una clase View*/}
}

if(isset($_POST['metodo'])){
    PageController::ejecuta($_POST['metodo']);
}
```

¿Este método puede llegar a ser inviable o podría valer para hacer una página de subastas, donde se pueden ver mensajes (enviar y eliminar también), subir subastas y pujar y poco más?.

Gracias ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es algo subjetivo pero bueno...
Si está bien o mal no se puede decidir así, ahora si tu pregunta es si estas implementando de forma correcta el modelo vista controlador pues la respuesta sería un sí. Un controlador, que en el método que sea obtiene los datos del modelo y los devuelve a la vista, en ese sentido estaría bien. ¿Se puede mejorar? por supuesto, pero lo que tienes hasta ahora sería la forma más básica del MVC.
Te dejo documentación sobre el patrón MVC: https://si.ua.es/es/documentacion/asp-net-mvc-3/1-dia/modelo-vista-controlador-mvc.html

Si no quieres utilizar un framework ya existente porque quieres hacer uno propio, vas bien encaminado, ya solo tienes que mirar distintos frameworks para ir sacando la forma más eficiente de crear tu framework.

Te dejo también un enlace de un tutorial que te explica paso a paso como crear un framework PHP para implementar el MVC, esta muy bien explicado y quizás te ayude para comprender mejor el patrón MVC: https://victorroblesweb.es/2014/07/15/ejemplo-php-poo-mvc/

Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: De nada, edite la respuesta y te puse un tutorial que a mi me ayudo bastante, checkealo. Un saludo.